# R visUpdateEdges: creates new edges instead of updating existing ones

Tags: r, shiny, visnetwork

I have a dynamic network which I want to represent with R shiny and visNetwork. Depending on the node which is chosen, colors of the nodes and edges should change according to some external protocol/data (nodeslist & edgeslist in the code below).

This works quite well for nodes: I select a node and in all future time steps the colors of the nodes change according to the data. For doing so, I use `visUpdateNodes`.

But when I try to do basically the same for the edges with `visUpdateEdges`, it doesn't work correctly: instead of only coloring the nodes, new nodes are created (with the correct colors).

A simple example is here:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(visNetwork)

# some data - these values are for the updating process
nodeslist <- list(id1 = data_frame(R1 = c("red", "orange", "orange"), R2 = c("red", 
  "black", "green"), R3 = c("red", "cyan", "yellow")), id2 = data_frame(R1 = c("orange", 
  "red", "orange"), R2 = c("black", "red", "green"), R3 = c("orange", "red", 
  "yellow")), id3 = data_frame(R1 = c("orange", "orange", "red"), R2 = c("black", 
  "yellow", "red"), R3 = c("brown", "cyan", "red")))

edgeslist <- list(id1 = data_frame(R1 = c("red", "orange", "orange"), R2 = c("red", 
  "black", "green"), R3 = rep("black", 3)), id2 = data_frame(R1 = c("orange", 
  "red", "orange"), R2 = c("black", "red", "green"), R3 = rep("black", 3)), 
  id3 = data_frame(R1 = c("orange", "orange", "red"), R2 = c("black", "yellow", 
    "red"), R3 = rep("black", 3)))

# the updating functions
changeColorOfOtherNodes <- function(nodes, selected.node, index) {
  nodes %>% mutate(color = unlist(nodeslist[[as.numeric(selected.node)]][, 
    index]))
}

changeColorOfEdges <- function(edges, selected.node, index) {
  edges %>% mutate(color = unlist(edgeslist[[as.numeric(selected.node)]][, 
    index]))
}


# making the network
id <- c(1, 2, 3)
color <- rep("cyan", length(id))
nodes <- data_frame(id, color)

from <- c(1, 2, 3)
to <- c(2, 3, 1)
edges <- data_frame(from, to, color = rep("#333333", 3), value = c(2, 2, 2))



# shiny application
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$netplot <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% visOptions(nodesIdSelection = list(enabled = TRUE))
  })

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$netplot_selected) && input$netplot_selected > 0) {

      for (i in 1:ncol(nodeslist[[as.numeric(input$netplot_selected)]])) {

        # updating works well for nodes
        nodes <- changeColorOfOtherNodes(nodes, input$netplot_selected, 
          index = i)
        visNetworkProxy("netplot") %>% visUpdateNodes(nodes)
        Sys.sleep(1)
        # updating for edges -> new edges are creates, but don't know why
        edges <- changeColorOfEdges(edges, input$netplot_selected, index = i)
        visNetworkProxy("netplot") %>% visUpdateEdges(edges)
        Sys.sleep(1)
        print(edges)
      }

    }
  })

})


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(mainPanel(visNetworkOutput("netplot"))))
shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

Has anyone an idea how to update colors of nodes with visUpdateEdges correctly? Why does `visUpdateEdges` create new edges instead of updating the existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `id` in edges `data.frame` and so use it to refer to existing edges in  `visUpdateEdges`

```
edge <- data.frame(id = 1:3, from = ....)
# update color of edge 1
visUpdateEdges(data.frame(id = 1, color = "red"))
```